# Share that only has write access.

Tags: ftp

We need to have a folder that is able to have a user write to the folder but not see the files after they have uploaded to the folder (blind drop). I am using Windows server 2012 R2. This was setup before however something has caused the permissions to fall off and now we cant seem to figure out how they were set prior. We use a generic account for FTP and need the account to only be able to drop files but not view the file after it has been dropped.

Comment: Searching "ftp blind drop" returned quite a few responses. Have you checked any of these out?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what has gone wrong when you've only told us that "permissions... fall off". A bit more detail and listing out the troubleshooting you've tried would be very helpful.

Comment: What I think has happened is the Share permissions were setup and we had performed a reboot to apply updates and when the server came back up the share permissions needed to be recreated. However I don"t know how the permissions were set before the reboot as I am fairly new to this office. I think I need to have a combination of share permissions and NTFS permissions but the right combo I am not sure of. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Solved--I was able to get this fixed by enabling Access-based Enumeration on the share. Permissions are set to List/folder, Read Attributes, create files/write data, create folders/append data

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. Write up your solution and post it as an answer and then accept it so others in the same situation will be able to benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Solved--I was able to get this fixed by enabling Access-based Enumeration within server Manager --> File and storage Services--> on the share properties then settings. Permissions are set to List/folder, Read Attributes, create files/write data, create folders/append data.